# How can I make sure that a plugin will not load until its dependency loads using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

Update 
I am using the jquery.validationEngine.js. plugin. My plugin jquery.validationEngine-en.js cannot run unless jquery.validate.min.js is loaded first.

In my HTML code I would load the scripts this way and it would work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/imagesrv/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/imagesrv/marketing/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

jquery.validationEngine-en.js is wrapped in the following

```
define(['jqueryValidateEngine'],function($){
//plugin code here
});
```

and jquery.validate.min.js is wrapped in

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
//plugin code here...
});
```

Now I am using required.js to load both plugins jquery.validate.min.js s is dependent on jquery.validationEngine-en.j in order to load. For some reason I keep getting the error "validationEngine is not a function" which means the plugins are not loading correctly.

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets",
  paths: {
    // The libraries we use
    jquery: [
    '/imagesrv/marketing/js/jquery.min'
    ],
    bootstrap:     '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/lib/bootstrap.wrapped.min',
    smartdevice: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/smart-device',
    main: '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/page/main',
    jqueryValidateEn:     '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEngine-en',
    jqueryValidateEngine:     '/imagesrv/marketing/requireJS/assets/js/jquery.wrapped.validationEngine'
  }

});


require(['main', 'bootstrap', 'jqueryValidateEn'], function($) {// Load up  this pages script, once the 'common' script has loaded
  console.log('jQuery and r.js have been loaded!');
});
```

Comment: instead of wrapping these libraries in a define the requireJS way to solve traditional libraries is via [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

So your config should look something like `'jqueryValidateEngine': ['jquery'],`

I'm not familiar with the library but maybe also an export

Comment: You wrote: "My plugin jquery.validationEngine-en.js cannot run unless jquery.validate.min.js is loaded first." but then the next code snippet shows `jquery.validate.min.js` is loaded *second*. Can you please review your question thoroughly and edit it so that it is not self-contradictory?

Comment: Thanks Louis. I will make the correction.